# Method to find word in string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am searching a string, there will be a line beginning with ssid and I need to find the word directly after that. So an example is "ssid home", home would be the word I wish to return.
I have done this in a roundabout way, seems very messy, what way should I do this, a regex perhaps or is there a way to tidy up what I have done?

```
a = """
!
interface blah
a
ssid test
v
v
"""

b = a.split("\n")
matches = [x for x in b if "ssid" in x]
matches = [i.split() for i in matches]
print matches[0][1]
```

Comment: How many times will "ssid" appear? Just the once?

Comment: Unless you're doing this for educational purposes, you might as well just use `grep ssid file -A 1` on unix/cygwin

Comment: @Ffisegydd yes just once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = """
!
interface blah
a
ssid test1
v
ssid test2
v
ssid test3
"""
p = r'(?<=ssid )\S+' # non-whitespace character chunk after ssid
match = re.findall(p, a)
```

This will give you: `['test1', 'test2', 'test3']`

Answer (score 3):

Split your string based on your key, `ssid` and then after discarding the first partition, iterate over the remaining partitions accepting only the first word and discarding the rest.

```
>>> a = """
!
interface blah
a
ssid test1
v
ssid test2
v
ssid test3
"""
>>> [e.split(None, 1)[0] for e in a.split("ssid")[1:]]
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

A similar regex solution would be

```
>>> re.findall("ssid\s+(\w+)", a)
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

Comment: You might want to do `e.split(None, 1)[0]`

Comment: @thefourtheye: Yes that would be nice suggestion.

Comment: If this is coming from a file, your regular expression should be `re.findall('^ssid\s+(\w+)$', a, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: very nice answers, the None syntax is new to me

Answer (score 1):

```
flag, result = False, []
for item in a.split():
    if flag:
        result.append(item)
        flag = False
    if item == "ssid":
        flag = True
        continue
return result
```

Lets do some time comparisons :)

```
a = """
!
interface blah
a
ssid test1
v
ssid test2
v
ssid test3
"""
import re
p = r'(?<=ssid )\S+'
def ray(a):
    return re.findall(p, a)

def abhijit(a):
    return [e.split(None, 1)[0] for e in a.split("ssid")[1:]]

def thefourtheye(a):
    flag, result = False, []
    for item in a.split():
        if flag:
            result.append(item)
            flag = False
        if item == "ssid":
            flag = False
            continue
    return result

from timeit import timeit
print "Ray", timeit("ray(a)", "from __main__ import ray, a, p")
print "Abhijit", timeit("abhijit(a)", "from __main__ import abhijit, a")
print "thefourtheye", timeit("thefourtheye(a)", "from __main__ import thefourtheye, a")
```

**Output**

```
Ray 2.4214360714
Abhijit 1.39024496078
thefourtheye 1.11726903915
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = """
!
interface blah
a
ssid test
v
v
"""

for line in a.split("\n"):
   if line.startswith("ssid"):
      result = line.split()[1]
      break
```

Using the for loop allows breaking out when the matching line is found rather than checking all the remaining ones.  Whether that is worthwhile depends on the length of the expected data.